# How to get OpenGL running on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I normally program on Windows, but I got a macbook pro from my school, so I'm trying to make an OpenGL app for OSX. I downloaded and installed XCode, but I have no clue how to get a simple OpenGL app going. I would prefer not to use Objective-C, but I definitely don't want to use GLUT. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest difference between OpenGL on OS X compared to pretty much everything else is the location of the header files.  On OS X:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

If you want to stay away from Objective-C/Cocoa and GLUT you can try [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org) which is a cross platform gaming library (windows, 2D graphics, sound, input, etc.).

Edit: forgot about the compiler flags, which mipadi posted, namely:

```
-framework OpenGL
```

Comment: I was considering SDL. I've used it before in a student project. But I want to learn the steps needed to create a window and then initialize OpenGL. I dont want to go through Interface Builder or have Cocoa automagically create a window for me.

Comment: Seems like I'm gonna go with the SDL route. Can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well Cocoa is the API for Mac OS X development, so I'm not sure how that's "automagic."  You use Cocoa to create a window in OS X just like you use the Windows API to create a window in Windows.

Comment: Right, I meant the way Interface Builder creates the nib that NSApplicationMain uses to magically create the window. If I can create the window manually w/o using IB, that would be great. The next step after that would be to create the OpenGL context and use that to draw on. I'm looking for that process, but for the mac. I don't want things to be hidden from me. I want to SEE the creation process step by step.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I'm sure it possible to do it directly but alas, my OS X development knowledge is basically nil.  I know enough to get OpenGL and SDL running and from there it's pretty much the same as any other platform.  I did however find this series of blog posts about developing OS X apps without a NIB: http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/05/16/working-without-a-nib-part-1/

Comment: You can use the same OpenGL primitives for creating windows on Mac OS X as you use on other platforms.

Answer (score 7):

This question is extremely old in internet time, but the most straightforward way... is to just dabble your feet in Objective-C... Sorry.

My general way of approaching this is as follows:

- You can keep doing all your core programming in C++, no problem.
- Create a new "Cocoa application" in XCode.
- In the interface builder (where you edit your .xib file), find an `NSOpenGLView` object in the object browser, and smack it on your window.
- This bit is **important**: In the object inspector change the subclass to your own subclass (that still needs to be made). You can name it anything you like, for example `MyRenderer` or something.
- Hit [cmd]+[n] and create a new Objective-C class, `MyRendere`r.
- **Important!** Change the extension from MyRenderer.m to MyRenderer.mm. This way, XCode knows that it must compile for Objective-C++ instead of Objective-C.
- In MyRenderer.mm, override *at least* the following methods of `NSOpenGLView`.

  - `- (void) awakeFromNib`: Do your class initialization here. **Do not initialize OpenGL here, or your program will crash.**
  - `- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtRect`: Do your drawing stuff here.
  - `- (void) prepareOpenGL`: Initialize OpenGL here.
  - `- (void) reshape:(NSRect)bounds`: For when the view gets resized.

The good news is that you can freely mix C++ functions and classes inside MyRenderer.mm.
You can also make use of C++ `#include` directives alongside Objective-C `#import` directives. You can do C++ inside `drawRect` with no problems.

The bad news is that `NSOpenGLView` *does not redraw* the scene every x milliseconds. It will only redraw the scene once it feels it's necessary. You'll have to make use of Cocoa's `NSTimer` class for that.

Edit: Extra note: In the `drawRect` method, make sure to call `glFlush()` as well as `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]`. For some reason, only calling `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]` doesn't draw anything on the view for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this website as my reference for my project for Window, Mac and Linux. 
http://ysflight.in.coocan.jp/programming/fssimplewindow/e.html

The author managed to write bunch of good examples which helps you get going with your project in all platforms.

The end point is that, you have to use Objective-C for your window creation and you can program the rest of your code by using C++.

Answer (score 1):

When using OpenGL on Mac OS X, there are two things to keep in mind:

One, you have to link the OpenGL framework. Outside of Xcode, you can pass the `-framework` flag to the linker:

```
$ gcc -framework OpenGL -o my_opengl_program my_opengl_program.c
```

(Note that this flag only works on OS X.)

If you're using Xcode, you can just add `OpenGL.framework` to your linked frameworks.

Two, you prefix `OpenGL/`> in front of your OpenGL headers. For example, to include `gl.h`, use:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

Otherwise, programming with OpenGL on Mac OS X is pretty much the same.

Comment: I don't think you understand the spirit of the question. I'm pretty sure that, after doing the above, I won't be calling wglCreateContext. What I'm looking for is either skeleton code for creating a window and attaching a OGL context to it or some pseudocode that explains the procedure.

Comment: Seeing as how `wglCreateContext` is specific to Windows (as far as I know), then no, you wouldn't be using that on Mac OS X. However, you can use *just* the OpenGL functions to write an OpenGL program on OS X.

Comment: right, i know the OpenGL functions don't change. that wasn't the original question, but some of the info you gave is definitely relevant, so thank you for that.

Comment: Your original question asked how you get a "simple OpenGL app" running on OS X without using Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're programming on a mac, you can use any language you're familiar with. XCode supports compiling C++, so if you're familiar with OpenGL on windows, then it's a straight forward transition, though you will need to use the proper methods for creating an OSX Window (cocoa most likely).

If python is your thang, PyOpenGL is a python binding to OpenGL that is cross platform.

Comment: You can use the OpenGL primitives for creating/working with windows directly (no need to go through Cocoa per se).

Answer (score 0):

The non-Objective C library is [AGL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/AGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html).